# Create dinamically a Dataset to fill reports on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dataset, report, reportviewer

I am searching for a way to create dinamic Datasets to be binded to my reports
(I am using C# on Visual Studio 2015 Community). 
Can anyone explain how can I do it?
The first idea is to create a Dataset from a query then bind it to my report, 
but I cannot create a report without telling VS a DataSet (which must be connected to a DB using a static ConnectionString (VS purposes me only the Wizard, I have no idea on how to do it dinamically)

Example Code of what I would like to have:

```
DataSet myReportDS = ADO.getDS("SELECT * FROM" + 
"Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.pkey = Table2.fkey");  
    //here I am stuck because I don't know even how to add objects without a 
    //static connection to my report (Designer) and how to bind it.
```

Have also in mind that the DBMS is PostgreSQL.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found this article to solve my problem
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/magreer/2008/10/16/setting-the-datasource-for-a-report-at-runtime/
The problem in fact is that VS forces the user to have a static DataSet to permit the report creation. So basically I had to create a copy of my DB Schema in local environment, then I executed my queries normally and then used Report.Fill() method. As soon as the schema is the same it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SqlDataAdapter` or `OleDbDataAdapter`.

For example:

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
string queryString = 
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
```

There are more examples on the msdn site.

*Source:* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What you are saying is true, but there is a problem when building the reports using the designer in this way. It needs a static DataSet to be created. Look at my answer.

Comment: With static.. you mean typed datatset?

Comment: yes, sorry for my incorrect terms, I mean datasets defined by designer and not dinamically as objects. I hope you understand.

Comment: The way I solved that: create an instance of the typed dataset. Load the data via the DataAdapter and call 'typedDataSet.Merge(dataset)'